# How to use C Code in ASP classic JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, c, asp-classic, typedef

Is it possible to convert a C programming code into ASP classic or JavaScript? I'm using ASP classic for a website and have to change the code from C to JavaScript.

For example:

```
typedef struct xy { NIrtd_stValue skillsetId: stStatItem* next }S_stStatItem;
```

How can I write this in JavaScript? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write this in JavaScript.  Data types cannot be aliased via ASP.

Comment: Is the a possibility to display a realtime data on using sap classic?

Comment: @MiMeng, do you mean without refreshing the page?

Comment: yes, the data has to be displayed live on the website

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the closest language, syntax and power-wise, to use here would be Java. Java can be used server side as can JScript, VBScript, C#.
Javascript is only for client side.

Comment: so that means i can't display a realtime data by using asp classic?

Comment: ok, you can use ASP to grab the data from a database and then generate html to send as a web page to the browser. You will need to translate all your 'C' code into ASP though

Comment: exactly this is what I wanna do but have no idea how to do ist. I'm using ASP Classic and I still can't a way to translate the C Code

Comment: Try googling for some code conversion services. One here:

https://www.varycode.com/

It looks like your code is C though and not C++. You may not find an easy quick way to do this. Highly likely that you'll need to manually translate this line by line unfortunately.

Comment: ok, thanks, I already noticed that this code conversion is really complicated, maybe I will try wih coding in c code for displaying the data live on website. Thank you for the information